# JQuery doesn't remove class by internal item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I want create a multi level off-canvas menu but i fell in a error because Jquery doesn't remove class by child item. in example you can see that when you press "back" nothing appen and if you used developer tool of chrome you can see that something appen to a div class but it doesn't be remove.

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93v8mghr/1/)

```
$(function(){       
    $(".m-nav-back").click(function(){
            $(".under-level").removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening as the event is bubbling, so the class is being removed on `back`'s click then after it has been readded. So try to use:

[`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

Also, you don't need to check whether the element has class and then remove it. Simply toggle it:

```
$(".m-nav-opener").click(function(){
    $("body").toggleClass("m-nav-open");
});
```

Also, you don't need to use `$(function() { blah blah });` multiple times.

Here is the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/93v8mghr/5/).

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$(function(){       
    $("body").on('click',".m-nav-back",function(){
            $(".under-level").removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

because sometime multiple layers does not work on direct click event of and element so you need to fire using body elements

This will work 100%

```js
$(function(){  
 $(".m-nav-opener").on('click',function(){
  if ($("body").hasClass("m-nav-open")){
   $("body").removeClass("m-nav-open");
  } else {
   $("body").addClass("m-nav-open");
  }
 });
});
$(function(){  
 $("nav li:has(div)").click(function(){
   $(this).children("div").addClass("active");
 });
});
$(function(){  
 $("body").on('click',".m-nav-back",function(){
   $(".under-level").removeClass("active");
 });
});
```

```css
.m-nav-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1001;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #DEDEDE;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  left: -300px;
        transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
}
body {
    transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;    
}
.m-nav-open {
    transform: translateX(300px);
}
nav ul {
    list-style: outside none none;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}
nav li {
    display: block;
border-radius: 0px;
margin: 0px 0px 3px;
}
nav li a {
    display: block;
color: #383838;
padding: 15px;
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 0px;
transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0s;
cursor: pointer;
}
nav li div {
    list-style: outside none none;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
top: 0px;
position: absolute;
left: 300px;
z-index: 2;
width: 300px;
height: 100%;
background: #DEDEDE none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
}
.active {
    transition: all 0.8s ease 0s;
transform: translateX(-300px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="soround">
    <div class="m-nav-container">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a>content</a></li>
                <li><a>content</a></li>
                <li><a>content</a></li>
                <li> <a>TOUCH ME</a>
                    <div class="under-level">
                        <ul>
                            <li><button class="m-nav-back">BACK</button><li>
                            <li><a>content 2</a></li>
                            <li><a>content 2</a></li>
                            <li><a>content 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <button class="m-nav-opener">MENU</button>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
            <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
                <p>content</p>
    
</div>
```